# Simple tkinter gui for already existing code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some already written code (btw I'm still a noob at python and programming in general) and i want to make a tkinter window that has a text box that is gonna show everything printed in the console and a button that is gonna run the main() function.

my existing code:

```
import pafy
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment


def downloadSound(videourl):

    url = str(videourl)
    video = pafy.new(url) 

    bestaudio = video.getbestaudio() 
    print(video.title, video.author, video.length)
    bestaudio.download() 

def linklister(linklist):

    f = open('links.txt','r')

    for line in f:
        linklist.append(line.strip())

    f.close()    

def converter():
    dirlist = os.listdir()

    songlist = []

    for i in dirlist:
        if ".webm" in i:
            songlist.append(i)

    for i in songlist:

        sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i)

        imp3 = i.replace(".webm", ".mp3") 

        sound.export(imp3, format="mp3", bitrate="192k")

        print (i, "DONE")

def main():
    ytlinks = []

    linklister(ytlinks)

    for i in ytlinks:
        downloadSound(i)

    print ("downlad complete, proceeding to conversion")

    converter()




try:
    main()

except Exception as e:
    print (e)
    print ("OPPS")

else:
    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlow. As it is right now you are unlikely to get much help on your problem. The code that you show is irrelevant to the question you have (which relates to displaying things in tkinter). Please show us what you've tried so far and explain where you are getting stuck. Refer to this for guidance on how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this on how to create a minimal, verifiable and complete example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What part of your goal do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but from personal experience this tkinter code works, I am unable to check if it works within yours. If this code doesn't work, test it by adding a print where I placed the comment.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import pafy
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment


def downloadSound(videourl):

    url = str(videourl)
    video = pafy.new(url) 

    bestaudio = video.getbestaudio() 
    print(video.title, video.author, video.length)
    bestaudio.download() 

def linklister(linklist):

    f = open('links.txt','r')

    for line in f:
        linklist.append(line.strip())

    f.close()    

def converter():
    dirlist = os.listdir()

    songlist = []

    for i in dirlist:
        if ".webm" in i:
            songlist.append(i)

    for i in songlist:

        sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i)

        imp3 = i.replace(".webm", ".mp3") 

        sound.export(imp3, format="mp3", bitrate="192k")

        print (i, "DONE")

def main():
    ytlinks = []

    linklister(ytlinks)

    for i in ytlinks:
        downloadSound(i)

    print ("downlad complete, proceeding to conversion")




class TextOut(tk.Text):

    def write(self, s):
        self.insert(tk.CURRENT, s)

    def flush(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = TextOut(root)
    sys.stdout = text
    text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    main()#here
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank I will try it.